# mfc120d.dll is missing after opening my project exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC vc++ project and I have exe file for this project using Visual Studio 2013. When I open the project exe it is working fine on my development machine.

But when I open this exe in my customer's machine, I'm getting this error message:

> The program can't start because mfc120d.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

[image]

I noticed that my project exe file is working if the system has Visual Studio installed. I also installed "**Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013**", but even then I'm getting same error. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. _mfc120.dll_ is not missing but _mfc120**d**.dll_ is missing. Your have deployed the debug version of your .exe on the customer machine. Deploy the release version instead. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939558/the-program-cant-start-because-mfc120ud-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program can't start because mfc120ud.dll is missing from your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939558/the-program-cant-start-because-mfc120ud-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer)

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. I installed 32bit version of Visual C++ Redistribute and i removed unwanted third-party debug dlls in my project. now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you deployed a debug version of your app. If this was intentional (to be able to debug remotely? ) you can find and deploy the mfc120d.dll from your VS2013 installation directory.
Otherwise just build the Release configuration and you should be fine.